# Не выводит элементы массива char

Tags: c, массивы, char, realloc, calloc

Это код ввода массива char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    int i,j,k;
    char *a,*tmp;
    if (!(a=(char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char)))){
        puts("Not enough memmory");
        return 0;
    }
    k=0;
    while(k<10){
        scanf(" %c", (a+k));
        printf("char is %c\n", *(a+k));
        k++;
        if(!(tmp=realloc(a,k*sizeof(char)))){
            printf("Not enough memmory");
            return 0;
        } else {
            a=tmp;
        }
    }
```

При выводе появляется только первый элемент массива, а остальные выводятся как как пробелы

```
printf("k is %d", k);
for (i=0;i<k;i++){
    printf(" %c ", *(a+i));
}
printf("end");
```

Вот output

```
1
char is 1
2

F:\Code>a
1
char is 1
2
char is 2
3
char is 3
4
char is 4
5
char is 5
6
char is 6
7
char is 7
8
char is 8
9
char is 9
0
char is 0
k is 10 1                            end
```

В чем может быть проблема такого поведения?

Comment: У меня в Linux работает, хотя в размере, запрашиваемом в `realloc()` (как указал в ответе @Vladimir), безусловно есть ошибка (надо просить на 1 больше)

Comment: А почему у вас на результат `calloc` налеплено ненужное приведение типа `(char *)`, а на результат `realloc` - внезапно не налеплено. Вы уж определитесь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вы же сами видите, что в еще до вашего цикла размер выделенной памяти равнялся `1`, а значение `k` равнялось `0`.

Это и есть инвариант вашего цикла - размер выделенной памяти должен быть на 1 байт больше, чем индекс того символа, который вы собираетесь читать. То есть в `realloc` у вас должно фигурировать `k + 1`, а не `k`

```
if(!(tmp=realloc(a,(k+1)*sizeof(char)))){
```

Не ясно только, почему вы делаете перевыделение памяти в конце итерации цикла, из-за чего у вас всегда будет выделяться лишний элемент массива

```
char *a = NULL;
int k = 0;

while (k < 10)
{
  char *tmp = realloc(a, (k + 1) * sizeof *a);
  if (tmp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Not enough memory");
    return 0;
  } 
  else 
    a = tmp;

  scanf(" %c", &a[k]);
  ++k;
}
```

И никакой предварительный `calloc`, как видите, не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо больше, помогло) Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему sizeof(char) == sizeof *a?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот, допустим, ввели Вы первое значение, затем стало `k=1` и Вы вызываете `tmp=realloc(a,k*sizeof(char))` - Вы думаете, что размер массива стал равен 2 байта (2 элемента)? А на следующей итерации он стал 3 байта?.. и т.д. Вот все, кроме первого элемента и теряются при вызовах `realloc()`. Видимо, очевидный способ исправить дело, добавить 1 к размеру: `tmp=realloc(a, (k+1)*sizeof(char))`.

PS: Вроде бы, по определению оператора `sizeof` в языке C `sizeof(char) == 1`, и его можно вообще не писать для вызова `realloc()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    int i,k;
    char *a,*tmp;
    if (!(a=(char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char)))){
        puts("Not enough memmory");
        return 0;
    }
    k=0;
    while(k<10){
        scanf(" %c", (a+k));
        printf("char is %c\n", *(a+k));
        k++;
        if(!(tmp=realloc(a,k+1))){
            printf("Not enough memmory");
            return 0;
        } else {
            a=tmp;
        }
    }

    printf("k is %d", k);

    for (i=0;i<k;i++){
        printf(" %c ", *(a+i));
    }
    printf("\nend\n");

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```